# Plateform or device type in react native

Tags: react-native, device

Platform or device type in React native

(I need it because I want to implement some functionality related to device -like iphone or ipad)

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

console.log(Platform.OS);
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

 if (Platform.Version === 25) {
 console.log('Running on Nougat!');
}
```

Detecting Ios version

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

const majorVersionIOS = parseInt(Platform.Version, 10);
 if (majorVersionIOS <= 9) {
 console.log('Work around a change in behavior');
}
```

For more details you can check their Official Docs

here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html